# Is there a way in rails where a product name can be isolated between brand and product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently building a rails application where we've implemented a barcode scanner. The app will then call an API to display the information of the product which includes the product name, manufacturer and other related information. The product name consists of the brand and the actual product (i.e. Dole Organic Bananas), is there some way I could isolate the actual product (i.e. bananas) from the brand?

New to coding and rails, so any help is appreciated! Even if there is no practical way of achieving this...

Comment: can you add more example of input data, like json file, or at least txt, currently it is unclear to what deal with.

Comment: Hi sorry, it is a JSON file. It looks something like this: 
{"code": 1,"msg": "Success！","data": {"goodsName": "Dole Organic Bananas","barcode": "6938176301376","price": "","brand": "Dole","standard": "500g"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the json you posted you have the goodsName: "Dole Organic Bananas" and the brand "Dole". You could try to just manipulate the strings

```
goods_name.sub(brand, "")
```

This would take our the brand name from the goodsName and you would get "Organic Bananas"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, `products` should belong to `brands`.  Once you have established that relationship, you could create a model method on `products` that would achieve what you are looking for. Something like what follows:

```
# brands definition
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products

end
```

```
# products definition
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: :brand

  def full_name
    "#{brand.name} #{name}"
  end
end
```

Then you could invoke the product name by calling something like

```
Product.find(some_id).full_name
```

Comment: I think what he is asking is if the product name is `Dole Organic Bananas` can he just show `bananas`.

Comment: Oof, if that's the case I suppose I didn't understand what he was asking

Comment: My apologies. Seems like my question wasn't clear enough but yes we have the result from the barcode - just can't think of a way to just isolate the product from the brand.